# Angular: Make an element appear on top, and relative to a button

Tags: css, angular, html, typescript

first of all, let me preface this by saying this might already be answered somewhere, but I couldn't find out how to describe exactly what it is I'm trying to achieve, at least not in wording that had any matching results.

here's a stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gvgj4s

I'm trying to build a component that allows the user to add a special needs service, as well as include a comment with it. 
Each service is listed with the help of ngFor and display: grid, and include a "comment" button.

I tried to illustrate what I'm trying to achieve on this image:
[image: 1]

An important feature, is that the comment "pop up", should be placed relative to the "comment" button pressed. Because of this, I included a ngTemplateOutlet within the ngFor loop.
The issue I'm having, is that when the "comment" button is triggered, everything get's moved around within the grid

I have tried having a div outside the ngFor loop which works, but it's not positioned relative to the button where it's clicked.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: something like this bootstrap functionality? https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/tooltips/ You can have a look how they implemented it and copy whatever you need

Comment: I looked at this, but the problem is that you should be able to edit a comment, which I'm not sure is doable with tooltip's, but I will take a close look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This is what I have](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mgkr7k?file=src/app/app.component.ts) after adding `position:relative` and `position:absolute`;

relevant **CSS** change:

```
.add-comment-container {
  position: relative;  
  height: 5rem;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 1;
  left:20%;
  border: solid 1px green;
  border-radius:20%;
  padding:5%;
}

.commentComtainer{
  position:absolute;
}
```

after relevant **HTML** change:

```
<section class="p-md green-border">
  <div class="common-ssrs">
    <div *ngFor="let service of commonSsrs" class="d-flex justify-content-between">

    <div class="d-flex align-items-center">{{service.code | uppercase}}</div>

      <div class="actions d-flex align-items-center">
        <button mat-mini-fab class="add-button" id="'wt-common-ssrs-add-' + service.code"><span class="font-title-1 add-text">+</span></button>
        <!-- Maybe change to button, to avoid marking when clicking -->
        <div class="mat-icon-container">
          <button (click)="editComment(service)" class="color-gray-2 cursor-pointer add-comment" id="'wt-common-ssrs-comment-' + service.code">comment</button>
        </div>        
      </div>
      <div *ngIf="serviceCommentEdit && serviceCommentEdit.id === service.id" class='commentComtainer'>
        <ng-container  *ngTemplateOutlet="EditSsrComment; context: { service: service, index: index}"></ng-container>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<!-- <div *ngIf="serviceCommentEdit" class="add-comment-container p-md d-flex"> -->

  <ng-template let-service="service" let-serviceIndex="index" #EditSsrComment  >
      <div class="add-comment-container p-md d-flex">
        <textarea matInput></textarea>
        <br />
        <button class="d-flex align-self-end" (click)="closeEditComment()">clear</button>

      </div>
  </ng-template>
<!-- </div> -->
```

Comment: Wow, this looks like exactly what I'm looking for! I will look into it a bit more, but thanks a ton so far :)

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
.common-ssrs > div {
  position: relative;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.common-ssrs > div > div:not(.d-flex) {
  width: 100%;
}
.common-ssrs > div > div:not(.actions) .add-comment-container {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 100%;
  width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Luckily, there is a plugin which does exactly what you're trying to archive!
It's called X-Editable, and it's compatible with Angular.
See http://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable/#textarea for documentation on the textarea editor (as a in-place "popup")

You can see a simple demonstration of this plugin on [JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/ckosloski/NfPcH/19041/).
This is all the HTML you'll need, along with some JS:

```
<a href="#" editable-textarea="user.desc" e-rows="7" e-cols="40">
    <pre>{{ user.desc || 'no description' }}</pre>
</a>
```

Comment: After reading a bit about it, it seems like x-editable is more related to being able to edit the text of a div, where as I'm looking for creating the div, but thanks for the suggestion :)

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the `position: relative;` and use flex `order: X` instead:

[Changed Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xjlth1)

**HTML code:**

```html
<section class="p-md green-border">
  <div class="common-ssrs">
    <div *ngFor="let service of commonSsrs" class="d-flex justify-content-between">

    <div class="d-flex align-items-center column-1">{{service.code | uppercase}}</div>

      <div class="actions d-flex align-items-center column-3">
        <button mat-mini-fab class="add-button" ><span class="font-title-1 add-text">+</span></button>
        <!-- Maybe change to button, to avoid marking when clicking -->
        <div class="mat-icon-container">
          <button (click)="editComment(service)" class="color-gray-2 cursor-pointer add-comment">comment</button>
        </div>        
      </div>
      <div class="column-2" *ngIf="serviceCommentEdit && serviceCommentEdit.id === service.id">
        <ng-container  *ngTemplateOutlet="EditSsrComment; context: { service: service, index: index}"></ng-container>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

  <ng-template let-service="service" let-serviceIndex="index" #EditSsrComment>
    <div class="add-comment-container p-md d-flex">
      <button class="d-flex align-self-end" (click)="closeEditComment()">close</button>
      <textarea matInput></textarea>
    </div>
  </ng-template>
```

**CSS code:**

```
.column-1 {
  order: 1;
}

.column-2 {
  order: 2;
}

.column-3 {
  order: 3;
}
```

Comment: I like this idea, but when I try to run your stackblitz, it doesn't seem to change anything?

Comment: @Jesper You are right, I hadn't saved the latest change. The comment box now disappears between the box label on the left and the "comment" button on the right but it's definitely not as good as the accepted solution. Perhaps it'll still give some inspiration.